# meaning of these sentences about dancing

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

What is the difference between the below three sentences?

> I enjoyed dancing with you
>   I felt good dancing with you
>   I felt good by dancing with you

Answer (score 1):

There's really nothing to choose between the first two for most contexts (I'm not going to get bogged down in possible fine distinctions between ***feeling good*** and ***enjoying***).

The third version is fairly unlikely, because the preposition ***by*** in such contexts would imply *the use of a particular method **in order to** obtain a specific desired outcome* (often, with the implication that the method actually used wasn't the only one possible). This would quite naturally occur in a context like...

> *I calmed myself by having a cigarette*

...but you'd need quite a bit of contrived context to make that relationship work with ***dancing***...

> *I was feeling a bit miserable when I first arrived at the party. But I always find that how I feel in the first half-hour dictates how I'll feel for the rest of the night. I stood next to your joke-cracking brother for a few minutes, but that didn't work because I don't find him funny. So instead I felt good by dancing with you.*

(Not that it works very well even in that example, but hopefully you see what I'm getting at.)

Answer (score 1):

> *I enjoyed dancing with you*

You (person speaking above) liked dancing with me (the agreeable dance-partner).

> *I felt good dancing with you*

Dancing with me provided you with sensations or emotions you liked.  We can likely assume you enjoyed it.

> *I felt good by dancing with you*

*Dancing with you* becomes an instrument by which you obtained good feelings.  That sounds awkward because it is, and the only normal real-life way you'd hear this is if you were a robot and trying to discover how you can feel good, and you tried dancing as one possible method.

Comment: I think we're both singing from the same hymn-sheet here (feel free to revert my edit if you think it's a bit "fussy"). In principle yours might be "better" if only because it's *shorter*, but I'm not really able to judge them impartially. Besides which as a native speaker I can't be sure exactly what's most likely to hit the spot for non-native speakers, so I guess we should just leave them both and see how the votes play out.

Comment: How about this one. I felt good by meeting you, I felt good meeting you, I felt good to meet you. What is the difference in these three?